# Limit MQFTE file transfer to one file at a time

Tags: websphere-mq-fte

I have a MQFTE setup where we are receiving files from an external vendor. The files get dumped on a server in DMZ and we have an MQFTE agent that picks the files from that server and drops to our server.

We receive files in "sets" i.e. each incoming file has an associated xml file that describes and contains metadata about the file. E.g. a applicationform.pdf and applicationform.xml. The final application stores the pdf file based on the data/metadata in the xml.

Since the trigger is fired for each incoming file, we check in the trigger whether or not we've received the XML file and the content file (e.g. PDF).

However, I don't think this is the best approach as it adds to a lot of booking code to check for concurrency issues when both files arrive at same time. Is there a way to :

1. Restrict the trigger so that it only fires when both files have arrived? In my research this is not possible.
2. Configure the agent on the server so that it only receives one file at a time? Looking at the documentation, it seems like it can achieved but only on the agent initiating the transfer, not on the agent receiving the transfer? The documentation hints at monitorMaxResourcesInPoll and -bs parameter, but that would be on the source agent I guess. Since the agent is shared with multiple systems, this would impact them as well.

Also, I would appreciate any tips and suggestions or even alternative solutions to best meet the requirement.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way to check for both files existing before the monitor triggers. What some users do is send all of the files they want to transfer, and then finally put a 'marker' file in the directory which the resource monitor looks for. Because the marker file is only written after all other files are ready to be sent, the monitor only transfers the files when they're all there.

In answer to 2) I you could set maxDestinationTransfers to 1 on the destination agent to limit it to receive a single transfer at a time. If a transfer contains multiple files they will be transferred in sequence so the destination is really only receiving 1 file at a time. monitorMaxResourcesInPoll simply limits the monitoring agent to the number of files it parses in the source directory per monitor poll. You could set that to 1 but if you want to transfer the PDF and the XML file in the same transfer you'd need to set it to 2. It's probably not the setting you want to use.